# issue on EPSON printer (Dot Matrix Printer)…?

Tags: printer, batch-file

our EPSON-DOT MATRIX printer.

not printing on DOS command

```
Type text.txt>prn
text.txt file..??
```

But - it prints on `open TEXT.txt>File>Print` - it works perfectly.

Comment: +1 for asking about (and presumably still needing) DOS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try **copy text.txt prn**.  If that doesn't work, try appending a formfeed character to the end of the document (that's Control-L) and then printing the document.

Comment: message--> this system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Try **copy text.txt prn:** or **copy text.txt lpt1:**.  That last one will only work if it's a parallel printer connected to the first parallel port.

Answer (score 0):

Yup it worked with this command:

```
Type textfile.txt>lpt3
```

The printer was connected to LPT3 port.

Answer (score -1):

Try This Step You  Got Resolved This Issue.
Type Following cmd "textfile.txt>lpt3"
After Typing This press"Enter" Now, You get Resolve from that issue.

Comment: That only works if your printer is attached to an LPT port.